# Wordpress show the_title() if title present

Tags: php, wordpress, title

What I want is the following: If a post has a title, I want to show it

In the [wordpress.org codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) you can see the following examples:

```
<?php the_title( $before, $after, $echo ); ?>
```

and this example:

```
<?php the_title('<h3>', '</h3>'); ?>
```

What I am trying to do, is I add a hyperlink with the_permalink in href

```
<?php the_title('<h3><a href=" the_permalink(); ">', '</a></h3>'); ?>
```

This however does not work.

In other words: how do I write **the_permalink();** in the code shown?

I also tried with:

```
<?php the_title('<h3><a href="' . the_permalink() . '">', '</a></h3>'); ?>
```

This results in:

mysite.com/?p=1

My Title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php $permalink = get_permalink(); the_title('<h3><a href="' . $permalink . '">', '</a></h3>'); ?>
```

Comment: "It's not work" doesn't help us determine what doesn't work. Be sure to provide any error messages.

Comment: I said! this code write this: mysite.com/?p=1 and MyTitle but I want write <a href='mysite.com/?p=1'>MyTitle</a>

Comment: also write: mysite.com/?p=1 and MyTitle separated, please first test yourself

Comment: because you break sections , the_title( $before, $after, $echo )

Comment: Where is the first part of that sentence?... and did you try my newest edit?

Comment: yes, I test <?php $plink = the_permalink(); the_title('<h3><a href="' . $plink . '">', '</a></h3>'); ?>

Comment: it's work <?php $permalink = get_permalink(); the_title('<h3><a href="' . $permalink . '">', '</a></h3>'); ?>

Comment: alright please select this as the answer if that is correct. have a good day

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop `the_title()` will echo the title. You can write it in this way

```
<h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(' ') ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>
```